# When I use VCR ignore_hosts configuration option all my other requests fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, vcr

I am using VCR with cucumber. I want to ask VCR to ignore all requests to "api.stripe.com" and do not deal with them. Let the requests go through to the real Stripe API server. But only those. I want the rest of the requests to be handled by VCR. So, I have the following VCR setup:

```
require 'vcr'

VCR.configure do |c|
  c.cassette_library_dir = 'vcr_cassettes'
  c.hook_into :webmock
  c.ignore_localhost = true
  c.default_cassette_options = { :record => :new_episodes }
  c.configure_rspec_metadata!
  c.ignore_hosts 'api.stripe.com'
end
```

When I run my tests all the tests that are accessing other external services fail. For example:

```
#<VCR::Errors::UnhandledHTTPRequestError: 

================================================================================
An HTTP request has been made that VCR does not know how to handle:
POST https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=<my_key>

There is currently no cassette in use. There are a few ways
you can configure VCR to handle this request:

  * If you're surprised VCR is raising this error
    and want insight about how VCR attempted to handle the request,
    you can use the debug_logger configuration option to log more         
    details [1].
  * If you want VCR to record this request and play it back during 
    future test
    runs, you should wrap your test (or this portion of your test) in   
    a `VCR.use_cassette` block [2].
  * If you only want VCR to handle requests made while a cassette is 
    in use,
    configure `allow_http_connections_when_no_cassette = true`. VCR 
    will
    ignore this request since it is made when there is no cassette     
    [3].
   * If you want VCR to ignore this request (and others like it), you  
     can
     set an `ignore_request` callback [4].
```

So, really,  I do not know what is going on here. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but perhaps you are not making the requests inside a `VCR.use_cassette` block or without the `vcr` metadata.
Please share a test example if this is not a solution.